# Icons awesome on same line

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to place these elements in the same line, both centralized on the left, and I could not, as a last resort, opted to ask for help

Demo:

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edwingperez/yh0ucvwt/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
<script src='https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js'></script>
<link crossorigin='anonymous' href='https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css' integrity='sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt' rel='stylesheet'/>
</head>
<body>

<a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-2x"><span class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></span><span class="fa fa-link fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></span></span></a>
<a href="#"><h4>Jennifer Lopez Ft. Ozuna – El Anillo (Remix)</h4></a>
<span class="fa fa-tag"></span> Label1, Label2, Label3 
<span class="label label-default">Musica</span>



  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to put some Html and css.

```css
.icon-img,.title,.label,.label-wrap{
 position:relative;
 display:table-cell;
 vertical-align:middle;
}
.cover{
 display:table;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
<script src='https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js'></script>
<link crossorigin='anonymous' href='https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css' integrity='sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt' rel='stylesheet'/>
<meta content='¡KLK! RD' name='generator'/>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="cover">
   <a href="#" class="icon-img">
    <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
     <span class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></span>
     <span class="fa fa-link fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></span>
    </span>
   </a>
   <div class="title">
    <a href="#"><h4>Jennifer Lopez Ft. Ozuna – El Anillo (Remix)</h4></a>
    <span class="fa fa-tag"></span> Label1, Label2, Label3 
    <span class="label label-default">Musica</span>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="cover">
   <a href="#" class="icon-img">
    <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
     <span class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></span>
     <span class="fa fa-link fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></span>
    </span>
   </a>
   <div class="title">
    <a href="#"><h4>Shelow Shaq - Musica Manteca</h4></a>
   </div>
   <div class="label-wrap">
    <span class="label label-default">Musica</span>
   </div>
  </div>





 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-1"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I navigate in responsitive, the icon takes one side and the other, I need to keep it in the same line

Comment: You can use "display:table; display:table-cell;" to keep the same line. You can check in snippet. I edited.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:flex` to `wrap` div. and wrap each section in div.

Use     `margin-bottom: 0;` to `description`(`h4`)

See fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/yh0ucvwt/16/

```css
.wrap{
  display:flex;
}
.description{
margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
<script src='https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js'></script>
<link crossorigin='anonymous' href='https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css' integrity='sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt' rel='stylesheet'/>
<meta content='¡KLK! RD' name='generator'/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrap">
<div>
<a href="#">
   <span class="fa-stack fa-2x"><span class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></span>
   <span class="fa fa-link fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></span></span>
</a>
</div>
<div>
<a href="#"><h4  class="description">Jennifer Lopez Ft. Ozuna – El Anillo (Remix)</h4></a>

<div>
<span class="fa fa-tag"></span> Label1, Label2, Label3 
<span class="label label-default">Musica</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: need put the description on middle

Comment: and icon stay in left side or middle with icon?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the grid system of bootstrap

http://jsfiddle.net/bf5j2nxd/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
<script src='https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js'></script>
<link crossorigin='anonymous' href='https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css' integrity='sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt' rel='stylesheet'/>
<meta content='¡KLK! RD' name='generator'/>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1">
        <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-2x"><span class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></span><span class="fa fa-link fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></span></span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-11">
      <a href="#"><h4>Jennifer Lopez Ft. Ozuna – El Anillo (Remix)</h4></a>
      <span class="fa fa-tag"></span> Label1, Label2, Label3 
      <span class="label label-default">Musica</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1">
        <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-2x"><span class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></span><span class="fa fa-link fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></span></span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-11">
      <a href="#"><h4>Shelow Shaq - Musica Manteca</h4></a>
      <span class="label label-default">Musica</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```